# Android volley can't handle a 2mb json file

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm hosting a json file in my vps and in my android app i'm trying to request it in order to save it in the user's device and so on. It's a 2.2 json mb file to be exact

Here's my code:

```
    public void sendJSONRequest(final String url) {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest  = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + "games.json", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Cool", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Log.d(TAG,"PLS: " + response);
            // mUpcomingGameReleasesList gets filled/appended with new data here
            // mUpcomingGameReleasesList.addAll(parseJSONResponse(response));
            // mUpcomingGamesAdapter.setData(mUpcomingGameReleasesList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Actually volley is not meant to be used for large data, volley store whole http response contents as byte[] in memory after it convert to String or Json or other type, so it can't handle huge response, you should use okhttp instead.

Comment: OkHttp it is. I'll try it out, thank you

Answer (score 0):

// try retry policy.

```
jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    30000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        mRequestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```